# Can anyone identify this lens?

Tags: lens, lens-design, fisheye

I read once, in a book, about a lens that was an "inverse fisheye".  Basically a hemispherical mirror mounted at one end of a glass tube.

I can't remember what it was called, nor can I find any record of its existance on the internet.  Sadly, I no longer have the book to be able to reference it.

Has anyone heard of such a thing, and can name it, or better yet, got one, and some photos from it?

[image: here's a drawing]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's a one-shot 360° panoramic lens. There are a number of examples out there with different mirror shapes; two of the currently-active vendors are

- [EGG Solutions](http://www.eggsolution.com/new/product/egglens.html)
- [0-360.com](http://www.0-360.com/)

They use different mirror shapes -- the 0-360 version is similar to your drawing, while the EGG is more like what would be left after a circle is swept out of a cylinder, so the effect (as a flat picture) would be different. The EGG is the only current one I could find that didn't have the mirror exposed and at the end of a long, delicate-looking stalk, but since I'm not looking for such a lens myself, I didn't spend a lot of time searching.

(When I wanted a 360° panorama in the film days, I rented a slit-shutter revolving camera. It opened the shutter and rotated the camera through a full circle while advancing the film -- sort of like a flatbed scanner for the world.)

Comment: Wow that's amazing that someone identified and found a lens (type) based on a basic hand drawing!  I'm impressed.

Comment: Not as impressed as I am.

Comment: I think it's rather worrisome and indicates some major deficiencies in parts of my life that ought to have seemed more important...

Comment: Unfortunately the EGG Solutions link no longer works :(