# Lumia 1020 with a camera grip mounted on a tripod - will it shake when I press the shutter?

Tags: tripod

I'm planning to buy a camera grip for my Lumia 1020. However, I'm little worried that when I press the shutter key manually by hand, while my lumia is mounted on a tripod, this can cause the phone to shake a little bit resulting in not so best shot. Although, I know Lumia has OIS built-in, I still have my doubts possible shakes. Is there any way I can remote click picture from say the PC or something like that? I'm new to phone photography, so please bear with me if this is a silly question.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would recommend doing is simply using the **self-timer** functionality of the software. You should be able to do this with essentially any smartphone software, but if the built in software does not allow for it, most downloadable camera apps do. Using the self-timer of 5-10 seconds it will allow the camera to steady itself from any hand induced shake before the image is captured. I use this technique all of the time when I don't have a remote shutter release available for my DSLR, and it works just the same on a tripod mounted smartphone.

Beyond that, we have quite a few resources already on this site that answer many of the questions that you have, see:

- [How can I prevent blurred images when using a tripod?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22125/how-can-i-prevent-blurred-images-when-using-a-tripod)
- [How can I determine the minimum shutter speed to avoid blur from camera shake?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1733/how-can-i-determine-the-minimum-shutter-speed-to-avoid-blur-from-camera-shake)
- [What are some techniques for hand-held image stabilization?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/178/what-are-some-techniques-for-hand-held-image-stabilization)

Comment: Spot on dear! My lumia actually does support the timer with the latest Nokia Camera app. The pre-configured duration is like 2, 5 & 10 second. Thank you for your help much appreciated!! :-)